# Google spreadsheet get cell value with row and column index

Tags: indexing, google-sheets

How we can get value from a cell in google spreadsheet?

I have row and column index from `ROW() and COLUMN() - 1.`

In other words what is the other way to do **"=B1"** i have row as 1 and column as 2.

Any suggestion, a single spreadsheet query. other than add function to spreadsheet.

Comment: A bit late, but I found an answer [`HERE`](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44725/get-value-of-cell-on-the-left-of-current-one) :)

Answer (score 11):

Say the row number is in A1, and the column number is in A2, any of these should work:

```
=OFFSET(A1;A1-1;A2-1)
=INDIRECT("R"&A1&"C"&A2)
=INDEX(A1:400000;A1;A2)
```

Comment: Could someone explain this madness?

Answer (score 2):

To do so use indirect() as such:

```
=indirect("'PAGE ASD'!"&A2&A3)
```

where A2 contains the letters to column like "D" or "AA"
where A3 contains the number to row like "2" or "35"
and the page you are calling the data from is called "PAGE ASD"