# Google Spreadsheet API Query Tabs

Tags: google-sheets-api

Can I query my spreadsheet tabs via tab index instead of the tab title or tab id?

https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{my sheet id}/values/'Hero Video Copy Section'?key={secret code}

'Hero Video Copy Section' is the title of the tab, but I want to find the tab via index.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776983/google-spreadsheet-get-cell-value-with-row-and-column-index)(quite old question). Given example is if the row number is in A1, and the column number is in A2:

```
=OFFSET(A1;A1-1;A2-1)
=INDIRECT("R"&A1&"C"&A2)
=INDEX(A1:400000;A1;A2)
```

Also, you can check this [documentation about Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets)  which uses an array to log the name of the second sheet.

```
 // The code below will log the name of the second sheet
 var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
 if (sheets.length > 1) {
   Logger.log(sheets[1].getName());
 }
```

Comment: I am talking about using the google Spread Sheet API threw a URL. I know how to get the name of the second sheet.

I would like to get the tab using the index value, so that the user has the freedom to change the name of the tab and it wont effect my call.